# ASP.NET Core API project exits before Main() is called

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, debugging

I have a .NET Core 3.1 API project that seems to have stopped launching under debug from Visual Studio after I hastily clicked through a Security Waring dial (shown in part below, excerpted from Hanselman's [blog post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/developing-locally-with-aspnet-core-under-https-ssl-and-selfsigned-certs)).

[image]

***I don't know if this action is what precipitated the failure to load*.**

What happens is the project `exe` appears to exit before invoking Program.Main() (verified that a breakpoint here does not hit). The full text of the **Output Window** is shown below after the break (I've attempted to pare down the wall-of-text, but need to show most of it for correct context).

I have tried various things to workaround the problem and/or to diagnose the issue:

- Cleaning and rebuilding
- `dotnet dev-certs https --clean`
- `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`
- viewing the certificate store (Windows) to see if anything is amiss (nothing is)
- Clearing NuGet cache
- Toggling **Just My Code** off/on
- copying the project to a new one and changing namespaces (to see if some sort of caching or prior association caused an issue)
- loading an old branch of code in which I've been able to do the debugging before
- modifying launchSettings.json in various ways
- setting *all* exceptions to break on (no exceptions occurred)

Adding new .NET API projects work as expected. It's the dialog that prompted me to think it was a cert issue, but again, I'm not sure.

---

**Output Window Text**

```
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\dev\Redacted.exe'. 
...
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\umpdc.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\5.0.1\hostfxr.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.10\hostpolicy.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.10\coreclr.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. 
The thread 0x7188 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.10\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.10\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.10\clrjit.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\dev\sdk2\Framework.ApiSupport.Tests.Controller\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Redacted.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\dev\Redacted.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Redacted.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.10\System.Runtime.dll'. 
'Redacted.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.10\System.Runtime.dll'. 
The thread 0x831c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
...
The thread 0x2008 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[37184] Redacted.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: "I don't know if this action is what precipitated the failure to load." -> Unfortunately, that's not related, at all. The SSL certificate is only needed after the project starts debugging and you open it on your browser. I'd say: delete /bin, /obj and /.vs folders (in all projects in the solution) with VS closed. If that doesn't work, try to clone the project again in a different location

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will try to clean again (I did clean those several times), but add a reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a complicated one. It turns out that a static class initializer in a third-party package was throwing an exception prior to `Main()` being called. This was also prior to any useful logging was available.

I only found this out by backing out as many dependencies as possible and building up until the exception occurred.

Hopefully this general answer provides a diagnostics path should anyone encounter a similar scenario.